# Deployment error. Error setting up the execution environment for your function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am unable to deploy firebase functions. This is the second day in a row.

I keep getting this error:

> Deployment error. Error setting up the execution environment for your
>   function.

I am not sure what is it am doing wrong since previously the functions deployed with no error.
[image]

Comment: If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.